# sfdisk don't like partitions - want to dump another hard drive to restore software RAID

Tags: linux, partition, sfdisk

I'm using Cent OS 6.5.

I have two Hard Drive which are exact copies of each others (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb).

/dev/sda failed and had to be replaced.

I am trying to copies everything from **/dev/sdb** to **/dev/sda**.

When I try to execute the command **sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda**, I get the following result :

```
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ...
OK

Disk /dev/sda: 121601 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Old situation:
Units = cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
/dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
New situation:
Units = sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      4096  41947135   41943040  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2      41947136 1952468991 1910521856  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3     1952468992 1953519615    1050624  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4             0         -          0   0  Empty
Warning: partition 1 does not end at a cylinder boundary

sfdisk: I don't like these partitions - nothing changed.
(If you really want this, use the --force option.)
```

**parted -l** returns the following :

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HUA72201 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags


Model: ATA ST1000DM003-9YN1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
1      2097kB  21.5GB  21.5GB  primary  ext4            boot, raid
2      21.5GB  1000GB  978GB   primary  ext4            raid
3      1000GB  1000GB  538MB   primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

I have also tried **sgdisk -R=/dev/sda /dev/sdb** but the command returns absolutely no output or error message.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 1):

> The requirement to align to cylinder boundaries has been gone for a
>   long time now. With the introduction of drives with 4k blocks and SSDs
>   with 128k erasure blocks it has become neccessary to align to
>   multiples of those instead. An alignment to 1MiB boundaries seems to
>   become the new standard and is what DI uses in squeeze.

[Source](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=602628)

You can use the `--force` option if you think that the alignment is OK.